# data.table alternative for dplyr case_when

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, data.table

Some time ago they introduced a nice SQL-like alternative to `ifelse` within `dplyr`, i.e. `case_when`.

Is there an equivalent in `data.table` that would allow you to specify different conditions within one `[]` statement, without loading additional packages?

Example:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a = c("a", "b", "a"), b = c("b", "a", "a"))

df <- df %>% mutate(
    new = case_when(
    a == "a" & b == "b" ~ "c",
    a == "b" & b == "a" ~ "d",
    TRUE ~ "e")
    )

  a b new
1 a b   c
2 b a   d
3 a a   e
```

It would certainly be very helpful and make code much more readable (one of the reasons why I keep using `dplyr` in these cases).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

FYI, a more recent answer for those coming across this post 2019. `data.table` versions above 1.13.0 have the `fcase` function that can be used. Note that it is not a drop-in replacement for `dplyr::case_when` as the syntax is different, but will be a "native" `data.table` way of calculation.

```
# Lazy evaluation
x = 1:10
data.table::fcase(
    x < 5L, 1L,
    x >= 5L, 3L,
    x == 5L, stop("provided value is an unexpected one!")
)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3

dplyr::case_when(
    x < 5L ~ 1L,
    x >= 5L ~ 3L,
    x == 5L ~ stop("provided value is an unexpected one!")
)
# Error in eval_tidy(pair$rhs, env = default_env) :
#  provided value is an unexpected one!

# Benchmark
x = sample(1:100, 3e7, replace = TRUE) # 114 MB
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
dplyr::case_when(
  x < 10L ~ 0L,
  x < 20L ~ 10L,
  x < 30L ~ 20L,
  x < 40L ~ 30L,
  x < 50L ~ 40L,
  x < 60L ~ 50L,
  x > 60L ~ 60L
),
data.table::fcase(
  x < 10L, 0L,
  x < 20L, 10L,
  x < 30L, 20L,
  x < 40L, 30L,
  x < 50L, 40L,
  x < 60L, 50L,
  x > 60L, 60L
),
times = 5L,
unit = "s")
# Unit: seconds
#               expr   min    lq  mean   median    uq    max neval
# dplyr::case_when   11.57 11.71 12.22    11.82 12.00  14.02     5
# data.table::fcase   1.49  1.55  1.67     1.71  1.73   1.86     5
```

[Source](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md), data.table NEWS for 1.13.0, released  (24 Jul 2020).

Comment: How the error message from tidy eval can pop up from data.table? Didn't you make a mistake during copy-paste?

Comment: Yes, Jan, I think I did. I'd copied it directly from the NEWS section. I've corrected that. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 22):

This is not really an answer, but a bit too long for a comment. If deemed inappropriate I'm happy to remove the post.

There exists an [interesting post on RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/will-case-when-stay-in-dplyr/11961) that discusses options to use `dplyr::case_when` without the usual `tidyverse` dependencies.

To summarise, three alternatives seem to exist:

1. [Stefan Fleck](https://github.com/s-fleck) isolated `case_when` from `dplyr` and build a new package [`lest`](https://github.com/s-fleck/lest) that depends only on `base`.
2. [yonicd](https://github.com/yonicd) developed [`noplyr`](https://github.com/yonicd/noplyr), which "provides basic `dplyr` and `tidyr` functionality without the tidyverse dependencies".
3. [Bob Rudis (hrbrmstr)](https://github.com/hrbrmstr) is the creator of [`freebase`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/freebase), a "A 'usethis'-like Package for Base R Pseudo-equivalents of 'tidyverse' Code", which might also be worth checking out.

If it is only `case_when` that you're after, I imagine `lest` might be an attractive & minimal option in combination with `data.table`.

---

### Update [29 October 2019]

[Tyson Barrett](https://github.com/TysonStanley) recently made the package [`tidyfast`](https://github.com/TysonStanley/tidyfast) available (currently as version `0.1.0`) on GitHub, which provides function "*`dt_case_when` for `dplyr::case_when()` syntax with the speed of `data.table::fifelse()`*".

### Update [25 February 2020]

There is also [dtplyr](https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org/), authored by Lionel Henry and maintained by Hadley Wickham, which "*provides a `data.table` backend for `dplyr`. The goal of `dtplyr` is to allow you to write `dplyr` code that is automatically translated to the equivalent, but usually much faster, `data.table` code.*".

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's quite helpful. I haven't heard about `lest` yet, which is indeed what I'll start testing. By no means I consider the comment inappropriate, I'll just let it stay for a while without accepting to see what other solutions `data.table` users may bring.

Comment: Might be worth adding `tidyfst` here https://hope-data-science.github.io/tidyfst/index.html

Answer (score 22):

**1)** If the conditions are mutually exclusive with a default if all conditions are false then this works:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df) # df is from question

DT[, new := c("e", "c", "d")[1 +
                             1 * (a == "a" & b == "b") + 
                             2 * (a == "b" & b == "a")]
]
```

giving:

```
> DT
   a b new
1: a b   c
2: b a   d
3: a a   e
```

**2)** If the results of the conditions are numeric then it is even easier.  For example suppose instead of `c` and `d` we want 10 and 17 with a default of 3.  Then:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df) # df is from question

DT[, new := 3 + 
            (10 - 3) * (a == "a" & b == "b") + 
            (17 - 3) * (a == "b" & b == "a")]
```

**3)** Note that adding a 1-liner is sufficient to implement this.  It assumes that there is at least one TRUE leg for each row.

```
when <- function(...) names(match.call()[-1])[apply(cbind(...), 1, which.max)]

# test
DT[, new := when(c = a == 'a' & b == 'b', 
                 d = a == 'b' & b == 'a', 
                 e = TRUE)]
```

Comment: That's a pretty cool hack! I'll benchmark & try it out a bit but it seems like something to use regularly with DT; though I'm not sure about developing packages with it as it may be a bit more difficult to maintain for some R users.

Comment: The user just uses the package and never has to see the code in it. It is the developer/maintainer who maintains it.

Comment: I agree that it should be like that. I've also tested the additional options you mention - they work great. I'm convinced with the 1st & 2nd approach for within `DT`, and may use the 3rd one to replace simple `ifelse` statements outside `DT`; it's just slightly slower than `ifelse`. I'll give this topic until tomorrow as there are no straightforward solutions and we may all benefit from other solutions, otherwise I think your approach summarizes it well.

Comment: Could someone please explain the principle?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, would you know if there is a way to use the `when` function with integers/numeric variables (without turning them into characters)? So that e.g. instead of `c, d, e` we would create `1, 2, 3` here?

Comment: For each row this returns i if the first logical condition to be TRUE is the ith. `when.num <- function(...) apply(cbind(...), 1, which.max); 
DT[, new := when.num(a == 'a' & b == 'b', a == 'b' & b == 'a', TRUE)]`

Comment: Thanks! This works - however, it automatically assigns the numbers. I'm also looking for possibility of manual assignment, but probably that's no easy one-liner.

Comment: If you want manual assignment use the original `when` and convert the result to numeric.  `when_num <- function(...) as.numeric(when(...)); 
 DT[, new := when("1" = a == 'a' & b == 'b', 
                 "2" = a == 'b' & b == 'a', 
                 "99" = TRUE)]`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a variation on @g-grothendieck's answer that works for non exclusive conditions :

```
DT[, new := c("c", "d", "e")[
  apply(cbind(
    a == "a" & b == "b", 
    a == "b" & b == "a",
    TRUE), 1, which.max)]
  ]

DT
#    a b new
# 1: a b   c
# 2: b a   d
# 3: a a   e
```