# data.table fcase versus dplyr case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

The following code throws an error when evaluating the line with fcase.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
tbl.test <- data.table(x = 0.5*(1:2))
tbl.test[, .(fcase(x < 1, x+1, 
                 default = x))]

tbl.test[, .(case_when(x < 1 ~ x+1, 
                        TRUE ~ x)
             )]
```

As I use case_when in this way (for most complex stuff ..), I wanted to switch to fcase, hoping a real gain in performance ..

Does anyone see where the devil hide with this usage of fcase ?
The point is that I can't use a column of my table as default value with fcase ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [data.table alternative for dplyr case\_when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031140/data-table-alternative-for-dplyr-case-when)

Comment: @ekoam No, unfortunately, it doesn't answer. Because the trouble I have is that, with fcase,  I can't give as a default value a column of my table ..

Comment: There is an open issue on the topic: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4258#ref-issue-650920677

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't explicitly state a question, but I assume you'd like to know if there's a way to use a vectorized default value with `fcase()`. One way to do that would be to construct a vector of `TRUE`s of equal length to your other conditions as the last element, similarly to how `case_when()` works:

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

tbl.test <- data.table(x = rnorm(1e6))

bench::mark(
  fcase = tbl.test[, .(fcase(x < 1, x + 1, rep_len(TRUE, length(x)), x))],
  case_when = tbl.test[, .(case_when(x < 1 ~ x + 1, TRUE ~ x))]
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 fcase        16.5ms   24.3ms     33.3     36.1MB     43.1
#> 2 case_when   146.4ms  147.9ms      6.60   129.9MB     28.1
```

Comment: Benchmark results pasted may be quite misleading. You could try to present measures in a common units, or just use microbenchmark.

Comment: @jangorecki I don't think the chance of someone misreading the units is terribly high, but I've updated the results. In general I prefer `bench::mark()` over microbenchmark due to also reporting memory use and checking that the results match. I could have set `time_units` to be equal, but there was no option for controlling the memory units (this might be a useful feature request), so instead I just updated the results with a smaller vector to get both units to match.